# How can I capture the same text multiple times using regex?

Tags: regex

I need to match the occurrence of a character before a string. The string might occur multiple times, meaning the character might change.

**Test subject:**

```
§aUsername: Message, which happens to contain Username. §3Wow, Username again.
```

I would want three groups, because `Username` occurs three times in the subject.

**Desired output:**

```
["Username", 'a']
["Username", 'a']
["Username", '3']
```

I wrote this regex, but it only works with one occurance of `Username`.

**My (failed) attempt:**

```
§(.).*?Username
```

Edit: That regex entirely ignores the second occurence of `Username`, which should match the same character (`a`) as the first one.

**Its output:**

```
["Username", 'a']
["Username", '3']
```

Comment: Are you sure your proposed output is correct?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no easy way to do this with a regular expression.  You're asking the parser to create two identical, but separate matches, which almost goes against the fundamentals of regex.  What you're asking for is certainly very possible, but regex is definitely not the tool for the job.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I can actually imagine how it would be fairly simple by just looping through each character in the string. Do you know if there would be any performance issues with doing that? That's basically what regex does anyways, right?

Comment: I'd say if it works it works.  For most practical applications, simply looping through a string is going to be, for all intents and purposes, instantaneous.  I honestly wouldn't start micro-optimizing performance until it actually becomes an issue, otherwise you'll drive yourself insane for no reason.  Depending on the language you're using, there may be built-in functions to get you started.  For example, you may be able to find all the occurrences of "Username" and "§" and work from there, rather than looping through each character yourself.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Yeah I've just been super paranoid about performance now that I'm getting more serious about making things other people actually have to use! Here's what I came up with in case anyone in the future is curious: https://gist.github.com/jxxe/83bbc81c9b1f6c3cfd3a8b8f262b484a

Comment: @jxxe That's about how I would've done it in Java, looks like clear, readable, and understandable code to me.  Nice job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a quantifier in a lookbehind is supported (.NET, Pyton PiPy module or the newer Javascript engines), you could use a capture group in the lookbehind.

The match will be Username, the group 1 will contain a single any character except a newline.

```
(?<=§(.)[^§]*)Username
```

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, asser what is to the left is

  - `§(.)` Match `§` and capture in **group 1** a single any char
  - `[^§]*` Match any char except `§`, using a negated character class, any number of times
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `Username` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1sdvQW/1)

Comment: While this is not the route I ended up taking, it does work correctly in regex for anyone coming here in the future. Edit: It doesn't work for Java's default library so I wouldn't have used it anyways, but it's still a good answer!